# Power BI Embedded, Pricing and Option

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need help with licensing and pricing about Power BI Embedded. Our client has **Power BI Premium Per capacity**, and we need to embed Power BI Reports within intranet sites. As per our understanding, we have the following option.

**Option 1:** Simplest and Easy. At app.powerbi.com, we have Embed Report -> Website and Port. We will get the iframe code, and then we can add it to any site—end-user must sign in whenever they want to check the power bi iframed report. Is this option required Power BI Embedded Server (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/)?

[image]

**Option 2 Using API:** This is more advance and needs development to get auth token and then render a report. If I am not wrong, before moving production, we need a Power BI Embedded as mentioned here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/), which is around 736 USD per month for A1.
I want to understand for which option we need Power BI Embedded capacity. Benefits to using Option 2 over Option 1 and Vice Versa.

Is there any free option to embedded the Power BI Report to any Web Portal?

Is embedding Power BI Reports withing Sharepoint Online need Power BI Embedded

Note: For the actual Prcings for Embedded, refer to this URL.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/

Comment: Below answers or more then enough, also sharing Power BI Community Reply : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-Embedded-Pricing-and-Options/m-p/1938508#M132813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of embedded, split by their type.

P SKU's -  the full Power BI capacity, turns your free users into read only, plus other features like 100TB storage, AI, Direct Query data flows etc.

EM SKU's -  Embeds reports into SharePoint & Teams, allows free users to consume reports

A SKU's -  Designed to host your own portal

Details on what you can do is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity#capacity-and-skus

However if you have EM, you have the rights to both host your own service, and also embed into your SharePoint/Team/D365/Secure Power BI url.
If you have P, you have the rights to both host your own service, and also embed into your SharePoint/Team/D365 as well as all the other features you get with P. If your customer already has Power BI Premium Per Capacity, 'P' type you do not need any other Power BI Premium Embedded capacity.

As for benefits between your options, it will depend if you want users external to your Power BI/O365 tenancy accessing reports without having to mess around with guest users in your AAD. If you want external users to access reports, it is recommended that you build you own portal to manage that.

P and EM SKU's can be purchased in O365, only A SKU's can be purchased in the Azure portal. Only A SKU's can be paused to reduce costs. As mentioned in your question while developing your solution, you do not need embedded.

There is no free option of embedding, reports unless you use the insecure 'Publish to Web' option. You also do not need embedded, for SharePoint/Teams etc, just that each user has a Power BI Pro, to allow access to the report. Embedded just allows you to leverage and reduce costs, by making free users as read only.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that as you already use Power BI Premium you also have power bi embedded funcionality. When you have the power bi premium option, you sure can share with your workers as they will have power bi login . You can embed as you said, in your portal and let people login with their power bi account, or share by sharepoint pages.
I'm pretty sure you can use all embed playground with your power bi premium account without having to pay another fee. Maybe you will need to expand your capacity . You can also understand if you really need a power bi premium or power bi embedded already works for you. The difference between them is that power bi embedded only allows you to embed the dashboards in web sites where you control the access .

Answer (score -2):

We did our own developed based in the Power BI Embedded playground at:
https://playground.powerbi.com/home
It's working ok, and you need a pro license and a server to put the nodejs development - we're using a azure vm :-) -